# Unable to run `redis-cli` on Windows 10 Enterprise machine

Tags: node.js, npm, redis, redis-cli

I have installed `redis-cli` on my `Windows 10 Enterprise` using node npm and it is now installed at the `location:`

```
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\redis-cli
```

I have also added the following folder to my `PATH Variable:`

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I am still getting the below error:

```
C:\Users\myuser>redis-cli
'redis-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with redis-cli, then my colleague advised me to use Memurai. That's Redis for Windows alternative. It works great. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rdcli` instead of `redis-cli`.
The usage is in the README file